# Include .exe in AIR installer

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I'm trying to create an installer file for my AIR app. I export release build and include all my elements, i.e. assets, a 3rd party .exe file, etc. But my output says file is damaged.

Is there s/thing about this .exe file that is doing this? Do I need to create a customer installer to handle running this? I'm guessing that if I want it installed silently then yes.

Thanks for any tips!

Comment: How are you exporting a release build?  Which version of AIR are you using?  What exe are you trying to include?  [and what do you expect it to do?]

Comment: I export my release build to an AIR file (as opposed to a native installer). In this AIR file, I'm trying to include a 3rd party .exe file (basically, a video component for my app). I would like to initiate the .exe automatically and have it set up all its DLL files and create its location, i.e. C:/my3rdPartyApp.

Comment: And my AIR runtime is: 3.1.0.4880

Comment: You want to initiate the .exe automatically how?  Using NativeProcess?  Or do you have an Native Extension setup?  Or something else?

Comment: Great question...I have no idea what the options are. What is the best approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://bishoponvsto.wordpress.com/2010/03/10/deploying-air-application-with-air-runtimeredistributable-in-single-exe/

Comment: This looks really good. I just have to figure out how to get installjammer up and running. I'm not so good with command line and the link for setup.exe for install brings me to an old page that doesn't exist.

Comment: Ok, I'm on the right path to getting this working. It seems like the .exe file should not be part of my AIR application's .exe. Instead, it should be separate and I should execute the action to install it via InstallJammer. I think I'm understanding it correctly. Thank you for your help.